# EXCEL VBA USERFORM - Make value negative if certain combobox selected

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am creating a simple spreadsheet with a userform to allow an admin assitant to enter transactions into a budget.  The only thing I've having a problem doing is figuring out a way to make a value negative (automatically) if the value in the Combobox named: entrytype is "Revenue"

Any help would be appreciated or even somewhere else to look at an example that's similar...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Entry")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).value = Me.entrytype.value
        .Cells(lRow, 2).value = Me.expense1.value
        .Cells(lRow, 3).value = Me.expense2.value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).value = Me.eventcategory.value
        .Cells(lRow, 5).value = Me.state.value
        .Cells(lRow, 6).value = Me.dateVariable.value
        .Cells(lRow, 7).value = Me.invoice.value
        .Cells(lRow, 8).value = Me.description.value
        .Cells(lRow, 9).value = Me.memo.value
        .Cells(lRow, 11).value = Me.TextBox1.value
    End With
    'Clear input controls.
    Me.entrytype.value = ""
    Me.expense1.value = ""
    Me.expense2.value = ""
    Me.eventcategory.value = ""
    Me.state.value = ""
    Me.dateVariable.value = ""
    Me.invoice.value = ""
    Me.description.value = ""
    Me.memo.value = ""
    Me.TextBox1.value = ""
End Sub

Private Sub expense1_Change()
expense2.Clear
Dim index As Integer
index = expense1.ListIndex
Select Case index
    Case Is = 0
        With expense2
            .AddItem "N/A"
        End With
    Case Is = 1
        With expense2
            .AddItem "Campus Tour Program"
            .AddItem "Events Off-Campus"
            .AddItem "Events On-Campus"
            .AddItem "Alumni Association"
        End With
    Case Is = 2
        With expense2
            .AddItem "Advertising"
            .AddItem "Promotional Giveaways"
            .AddItem "Publications-Marketing"
        End With
    Case Is = 3
        With expense2
            .AddItem "Recruitment Travel"
            .AddItem "Search Names"
            .AddItem "Travel"
        End With
    Case Is = 4
        With expense2
            .AddItem "Oper. Maint. & Upgrade Agreements"
            .AddItem "Furnishings & Renovations"
            .AddItem "Office Supplies"
            .AddItem "Postage"
            .AddItem "Telephone & Cable"
            .AddItem "Equipment Purchase & Repair"
            .AddItem "Training & Prof Develop"
        End With
    Case Is = 5
        With expense2
            .AddItem "Miscellaneous"
        End With
If expense1 <> -1 Then
    expense2 = expense1
    expense2 = -1
    End If

End Select

End Sub

Private Sub Image1_Click()
dateVariable = CalendarForm.GetDate( _
        SelectedDate:=Date, _
        FirstDayOfWeek:=Monday, _
        DateFontSize:=12, _
        OkayButton:=True, _
        ShowWeekNumbers:=True, _
        BackgroundColor:=RGB(243, 249, 251), _
        HeaderColor:=RGB(147, 205, 2221), _
        HeaderFontColor:=RGB(255, 255, 255), _
        SubHeaderColor:=RGB(223, 240, 245), _
        SubHeaderFontColor:=RGB(31, 78, 120), _
        DateColor:=RGB(243, 249, 251), _
        DateFontColor:=RGB(31, 78, 120), _
        TrailingMonthFontColor:=RGB(155, 194, 230), _
        DateHoverColor:=RGB(223, 240, 245), _
        DateSelectedColor:=RGB(202, 223, 242), _
        SaturdayFontColor:=RGB(0, 176, 240), _
        SundayFontColor:=RGB(0, 176, 240), _
        TodayFontColor:=RGB(0, 176, 80))
    If dateVariable <> 0 Then dateVariable = dateVariable

End Sub

Dim TextBox1oldValue As String

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1) Then
        TextBox1 = Format(TextBox1, "$#,##0.00")
    Else
        TextBox1 = TextBox1oldValue
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If IsNumeric(TextBox1) Then
        TextBox1oldValue = Format(TextBox1, "$#,##0.00")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1oldValue = "$0.00"
    TextBox1 = "$0.00"

With entrytype
    .AddItem "Revenue"
    .AddItem "Expense"
End With

With expense1
    .AddItem "Application Fee Expense"
    .AddItem "Campus Tour Events"
    .AddItem "Marketing Communication"
    .AddItem "Recruitment Outreach"
    .AddItem "General Operating"
    .AddItem "Miscellaneous"
End With

With eventcategory
    .AddItem "Application Workshop"
    .AddItem "Up Close"
    .AddItem "Scholars Day"
    .AddItem "Senior Day"
    .AddItem "Junior Day"
    .AddItem "Financial Aid Night"
    .AddItem "Academic Talent Event"
    .AddItem "PC Conference"
    .AddItem "Orange Friday"
    .AddItem "Gear UP"
End With

With state
    .AddItem "Oklahoma"
    .AddItem "Arkansas"
    .AddItem "Arizona"
    .AddItem "California"
    .AddItem "Colorado"
    .AddItem "Florida"
    .AddItem "Illinois"
    .AddItem "Kansas"
    .AddItem "Missouri"
    .AddItem "Nebraska"
    .AddItem "New Mexico"
    .AddItem "Texas"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: In all honesty I dont need you need to include every single line of code, especially stuff that is completely unrelated to your question (ex: Image1_Click)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a Change event handler for your ComboBox and make a simple test:

```
Private Sub entrytype_Change()
    If entrytype.Value = "Revenue" Then
        yourvaluehere = -yourvaluehere 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: shouldn't it be   `If entrytype.Value = "Revenue" Then yourvaluehere = - yourvaluehere ` ?

Comment: @user3598756 - Probably. Not sure why I assumed it was being driven by a checkbox. Edited.

Comment: This is great! So much simpler than I thought

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways to approach input validation, however, something like this may be useful:

```
If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Revenue" And Left(TextBox1.Text, 1) <> "-" Then
 TextBox1.Text = "-" & TextBox1.Text
```

ComboBox1 being the object containing the "Revenue" drop down and TextBox1 being whatever object you're taking an input into (all value fields you wish to change to a minus if Revenue is selected).

You could do something later on too, however, this will visibly show on the form before submission.

Comment: thanks! We ended up,using this solution as of course the simple project grew after our admin started using it... appreciate your help!